# TIBCO RV - Remote queue writing max message rate limits

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-rv

My application is located in HK and writes directly to a remote queue in Korea daemon. It is a single threaded application. Ideally, I should write to a local queue which should ship the message to remote queue.

Seeing the rate at which I am able to send messages to the remote queue, I am thinking either there is a limit on the TIBCO daemon for messages being written across WAN or there is a WAN bandwidth issue. It is also possible there is an application throughput issue (which I am investigating).

Question here is for the first part - is there any TIBCO limit that you can set to restrict the rate / the max number of messages per second when written from across WAN.

The queue being written is a durable.

Think I am seeing 22 messages per second.

Comment: Are you talking about TIBCO RV that doesn't have concept of queues (only Topics), or TIBCO EMS that have concept of queues and routing (with local and remote queues) ?
If this is Rendezvous there is no way to restrict the publishing rate

Comment: It is queues / ems.

Comment: In EMS there is no way to restrict the publishing rate either. If you are connecting to a remote EMS server it is likely for the slow publishing rate to be linked to WAN link latency.